# How to access dynamic number of inputs and HTML elements in Django?

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms

I am pretty new to all of this and am building a food order app. Now I am at a point where I have dynamically generated a page with JavaScript that contains a HTML-`form` with varying (potentially large) number or HTML elements such as dish name, price, amount, extra toppings (`input`s to be selected), etc and a "Place Order" `submit` button for a `POST` request.

Normally, in my Django-URL, I would access the submitted information (e.g. the input text named `username`) for example like this:

```
username = request.POST["username"]
```

But how do I go about it in my case? I need much more than only 2 text input fields with hard-defined `name`s. Is there a way of calling my Django url maybe with a large array or JSON object as parameter?

Comment: Should be `name="toppings[]"` in your HTML and `toppings = request.POST.getlist('toppings[]')`

Comment: @ChrisG thank you! I think that will help me with the user-selected inputs for toppings (and only of 1 dish!), but how about the other (already previously selected) order information that is already present in my HTML ```form``` in form of text in a table, tag attributes, etc? I.e. Django needs to know which dish, how many of them, etc, too.

Comment: It depends on how you're going to send it; if you're using basic form submission, all data needs to exist as `<input>` or `<select>` values. However you can also compile arbitrary data and send it as JSON. (Also, maybe keep the entire order in localStorage / the django session and only show a form dealing with one dish at a time?)

Comment: @Chris G - yes, I do use the localStorage and was thinking JSON, and apologies for this being so basic, but how do I send a (large) JSON object to my Django view via a ```POST``` request?

Comment: You can put it in the body like this: `fetch("django_url", { method: "post", body: JSON.stringify(order_data) }).then(...);` and here's the django side: https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/60061/get-request-body-as-string-in-django

Comment: @ChrisG will look into ```fetch``` - can this also be done with an ```XMLHttpRequest```?

Comment: Yes, fetch is just the modern, easier to use variant.

Comment: My problem though is that all I want is 1) send a JSON object to Django view via a POST request 2) use JSON object data in view logic, then render different template/url AND never go back to that 
original page that sent the JSON. I had that problem with AJAX callbacks (seems like same principle in fetch)
where you just cannot leave the page and the server has to return something to the client for a callback. And inside that callback you just can't call the Django url (with that JSON data that was already sent)...

Comment: If you want to avoid the single page app route (a once loaded HTML+JS interface exchanges data with the server via ajax/fetch/xhr) and rather create a traditional website where the user clicks links and sends forms to navigate to new urls, you can still collect all data into an object, stringify it to JSON, put it into a hidden `<input>` and submit its `<form>`. That way you aren't tied to writing a perfect `<form>` but can manually compile all the data, but then still send it to the server the traditional way.

Comment: And you can of course always just do `location = "/confirm_order";` in the ajax/fetch success callback to navigate there, and have Django show output based on the data sent via ajax previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out and followed advice in comments: the way to go here is a hidden html form that I populate and submit via JavaScript `document.getElementById("hiddenform").submit();`.

Here is the form:

```
<form hidden action = "{% url 'basket' %}" method="post" id="hiddeform">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input id="pizza_orders" name="pizza_orders" type="hidden" value="">
  <input id="sub_orders" name="sub_orders" type="hidden" value="">
  <input id="preselection" name="preselection" type="hidden" value="">
</form>
```

In my `views.py` I can then receive the data via:

```
def basket(request):

  if request.method == "POST":

    pizza_orders = request.POST["pizza_orders"]
    sub_orders = request.POST["sub_orders"]
    preselection = request.POST["preselection"]
    print(f"Preselection is", preselection)
    print(f"Pizza orders are ", pizza_orders)
    print(f"Sub orders are ", sub_orders)

    template = loader.get_template('pizza/confirmation.html')

  context = {"TODO": "TODO"}
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```